# svcutil failure to generate interfaces for self hosted wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

Can you please help me resolve my errors?

I am self hosting WCF in a WinForm assembly and I am trying to generate the client app.config and service interface. I am executing svcutil http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/  /Language=c#  /t:Code  /out:C:\Service\ServiceProxy.cs /config:C:\Service\ServiceProxy.config in the VS2015 developer command prompt.

I get the following errors:

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.

WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/'.

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
```

HTTP GET Error
    URI: http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/'.
```

### The request failed with the error message:

#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}ServiceService

The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
--.

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"

My self hosting code:

System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding MexHttpBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();

```
               String baseAddress = "http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/";
                NetTcpBinding tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
                tcpbinding.Name = "SEMSIntegration_NetTcpBinding_iSEMSIntegrationWCFService";
                tcpbinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
                tcpbinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
                tcpbinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
                tcpbinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
                tcpbinding.TransactionFlow = false;
                tcpbinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
                tcpbinding.TransactionProtocol = TransactionProtocol.OleTransactions;
                tcpbinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
                tcpbinding.ListenBacklog = 10;
                tcpbinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
                tcpbinding.MaxBufferSize = 524288;
                tcpbinding.MaxConnections = 100;
                tcpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 524288;

                WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                SEMSService = new MyOwnWCFService();
                SEMSHost = new ServiceHost(SEMSService, new Uri(baseAddress));

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = SEMSHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                // If not, add one
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                }
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                SEMSHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                SEMSHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());

                SEMSHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
                SEMSHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(iSEMSIntegrationWCFService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService");
                SEMSHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(iSEMSIntegrationWCFService), tcpbinding, "net.tcp://localhost:8888/MyOwnWCFService");
                SEMSHost.AddServiceEndpoint("IMetadataExchange", MexHttpBinding, "mex");

                SEMSHost.Open();
```

Comment: My WCF knowledge is a bit rusty. What happens if you change the svcutil command line to say `http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/wsdl?` ?

Comment: I pretty much get the same error (too long to add to this comment).

Answer (score 0):

```
This is because you are getting the error:

System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Menu' cannot be serialized.

See browser exception detail:

An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: http://tempuri.org/:iSEMSIntegrationWCFService ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Menu' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetDataContract(Type clrType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetMemberTypeDataContract(DataMember dataMember)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExportContract(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportContract(ContractDescription contract)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.get_Metadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)


Contract Definition:

<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="myService" behaviorConfiguration="MyDefaultBehaviour">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8880/MyOwnWCFService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>

      <endpoint
        address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="iSEMSIntegrationWCFService" />

      <endpoint
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetaDataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name ="MyDefaultBehaviour">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What's the contract definition?

Comment: Contract definition appended to answer.